# My network was compromised, what should I do?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, ipad

All wireless clients were kicked off the network (3 PCs & 1 iPad). Only a PC with a wired connection was still able to connect. This morning I discovered that the network had been renamed and a new password had been assigned.

Via Linksys Updater I gave a new password.  Strangely, in my Windows Control Panel/Network connections our old password now exists as an unsecured network, that I cannot delete!  When I attempt to connect using this bastard network, I get an Apple Push error.

- Linksys WRT610N
- PCs all using Windows 7 (wired & wireless)
- iPad 2

Comment: I edited your question, if you dislike the changes feel free to revert them or edit it again. Actually I don't think your iPad has anything to do with this, but question about tablets are mostly off-topic on superuser (check the FAQ).

Answer (score 8):

1. Disconnect the modem from the router.
2. Reset the Linksys WRT610N to factory defaults. You can usually do that via a special button or sequence of actions. Get the manual/info [here](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/routers/WRT610N).
3. Connect directly to the router with your most secure computer (wired). Do not have the modem connected to the router and nor any internet access wirelessly.
4. Change your default router password, to something strong and not used before.
5. Turn your wireless signal on but HIDE it from broadcasting. DO NOT use the same SSID. Use a strong password for authentication.
6. Connect the modem back to the router after your secure it. As  Darth Android suggests, you should run AV just in case the intruder left a backdoor. I would also check each computer on the network, including firewall settings.

Comment: Also, check your systems for viruses. Your network was not 'corrupted', but it sounds like it was breached by a hacker.

Comment: Check for the viruses before you plug on the router for the first time too. If you connect to the router with a virus/backdoor, there is a possibility the hacker will get/log the new password you use and it won't do anything. Bad hackers are like bulldog, once they close their jaws on something, they don't let go easily.

Comment: the person who got in is probably young...stupid or both. Why sneak in and then scream at the top of their voice saying "I am HERE, look at ME!". Which is basically what the person did by changing network settings.

Comment: I strongly disagree with point 5, despite the use of capitals, apart from the strong password, which is obviously a good idea. Hiding the SSID will neither prevent it from being broadcast or obtained by an attacker, nor make this significantly more difficult. The feature reduces compatibility, is in conflict with the 802.11 specification and actually opens up several security vulnerabilities. Unless you don't want to let the neighbours know you're operating a wifi station, do not attempt to hide your SSID.

Comment: You hide the SSID because the intruder is a neighbor or war-driver. The obvious is changing the default router password, and not having a public wifi that is open ( one which does not require a password for access ). These must be fixed. Hiding the SSID is secondary as is like arguing the security protocol  (WEP,WPA,WPA2 etc...). This intruder will tackle easier targets especially when you can get wide open public wifi networks off any street in any town elsewhere.

Comment: *> You hide the SSID because the intruder is a neighbor or war-driver.*   It doesn’t really matter since whomever did it is obviously hostile. You may as well assume that they are advanced enough to use any of the freely available tools that can scan for networks that aren’t broadcasting their SSIDs (and may even target those on purpose). `:-|` If there are lots of other networks in the area, you may as well “hide in plain sight”. `;-)`

Comment: anyone advance can get into any network if they wanted... just do not leave the front door open, a window cracked or the key under the mat :)